# What is the correct way to share directories with Ubuntu running in a Virtual Box VM with correct permissions?

Tags: virtualbox, permissions, mac

In VirtualBox, what is the best way to share a directory between an OS X host and Ubuntu
guest?

- Host: Mac OS X 10.7.3
- Guest: Ubuntu 12.04
- Guest has a shared directory mounted via VirtualBox settings with
  *Access=Full* and *Auto-Mount=Yes*.

The problem with this setup is illustrated below. In my shared directory, I
can't change the permissions at all (not a permissions denied error, but they
just don't take effect).

Ubuntu 12.04 (guest):

```
% ls -l
total 0
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 Apr 17 21:56 1
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 Apr 17 21:56 10
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 Apr 17 21:56 2
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 Apr 17 21:56 3
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 Apr 17 21:56 4
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 Apr 17 21:56 5
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 Apr 17 21:56 6
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 Apr 17 21:56 7
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 Apr 17 21:56 8
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 Apr 17 21:56 9
```

Mac OS X 10.7.3 (host):

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 <my-mac-user>  staff  0 Apr 17 21:56 1
-rw-r--r--  1 <my-mac-user>  staff  0 Apr 17 21:56 10
-rw-r--r--  1 <my-mac-user>  staff  0 Apr 17 21:56 2
-rw-r--r--  1 <my-mac-user>  staff  0 Apr 17 21:56 3
-rw-r--r--  1 <my-mac-user>  staff  0 Apr 17 21:56 4
-rw-r--r--  1 <my-mac-user>  staff  0 Apr 17 21:56 5
-rw-r--r--  1 <my-mac-user>  staff  0 Apr 17 21:56 6
-rw-r--r--  1 <my-mac-user>  staff  0 Apr 17 21:56 7
-rw-r--r--  1 <my-mac-user>  staff  0 Apr 17 21:56 8
-rw-r--r--  1 <my-mac-user>  staff  0 Apr 17 21:56 9
```

If I chmod on the guest, nothing changes:

```
% chmod +x 1 | ls -l 1 # guest
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 Apr 17 21:56 1
```

If I chmod on the host, it changes on the host but not on the guest:

```
$ chmod +x 1 | ls -l 1 # host
-rwxrwx--x  1 <my-mac-user>  staff  0 Apr 17 21:56 1

% ls -l 1 # guest
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 Apr 17 21:56 1
```

Comment: Ah, I figured it out, but I can't post the answer for another 8 hours (not enough points). The solution is to do `sudo mount.vboxsf -o umask=002,gid=1000,uid=1000 src /media/sf_src`, where the umask is the value of `umask` of the user, uid and gid are from `id <user>`, `src` is the name of the VBox share, and `/meida/sf_src` is the desired mount point.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've figured it out!

To reproduce:

1. Shutdown the VM, add shared folders in VBox's settings (Permanent=Yes, Auto-Mount=No)
2. Start the VM
3. From a terminal, run `umask && id` as the normal user to get something like this:

   ```
   002 # this is your umask
   uid=1000(luser) gid=1000(luser) groups=1000(luser),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),124(sambashare),125(vboxsf)
   ```
4. `sudo mkdir -p /media/sf_src # src is the shared directory`

To mount the `src` directory as a test:

```
sudo mount.vboxsf -o umask=002,gid=1000,uid=1000 src /media/sf_src 
                           |   |        |        |   |-> where to mount
                           |   |        |        |       the file
                           |   |        |        |-> name of the shared dir
                           |   |        |            (in VBox settings)
                           |   |        |
                           \   |        /
                        from the `id` command
```

To automatically mount it on login, edit `/etc/fstab` and add the following:

```
src /media/sf_src vboxsf umask=002,gid=1000,uid=1000
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! I ended up creating a shared user group for apache2 and my users that have access to the mounted folder.  http://serverfault.com/questions/6895/whats-the-best-way-of-handling-permissions-for-apache2s-user-www-data-in-var

Comment: Thanks! Note that I had big problems until I discovered that `/sbin/mount.vboxsf` was a dangling symlink! Erasing it and then `ln -s /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.10/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions/mount.vboxsf /sbin/mount.vboxsf` solved the problem!  The guest additions install probably wasn't able to symlink it. I spent *far* too much time figuring this out!

Comment: ... now the only problem seems to be that vboxsf doesn't handle symlinks! As in, you can't create symlinks in the shared folder from the VM! (At least on OSX, VirtualBox 4.3.10

Comment: This procedure certainly is one of a few to get you there.  In my case though, when I change to the shared directory and try issuing an ls command, the terminal hangs

Answer (score 4):

The problem -- permission issues in vbox/ubuntu accessing a OSX shared drive

```
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/$ ls /media/sf_shared
ls: cannot open directory /media/sf_shared: Permission denied
```

The goal is a simple way to to share directories between Mac and Ubuntu environments. Unfortunately the examples that I have seen so far seem to be a bit more complex than they actual need to be, and don't really explain what the real problem that needs to be solved. I'll attempt to to handle both of those issues here.

The environment here is a Mac running OSX 10.9.5, with Virtual Box 4.3.16 executing Ubuntu-14.04.1 with Guest extensions installed. September 2014 stuff.

I think that the entire problem here is that the **uid** of the directories on the Mac, and in Ubuntu must match — The default gid’s assigned for user and groups are different between OSX and Ubuntu,  and that’s where the trouble lies.

To access a file, one must either own it, or be a member of the group that owns it. And as access is actually based on the id number of the group, not the group name, all that is necessary is to create a common group number on both sides, that the users belong to.

That’s exactly what the solution below does. Don’t be mislead by the length of what’s written, it’s actually very simple. There are just lots and lots of examples of what’s going on.

I’m going to be flipping between **OSX** and **VBOX** consoles here (mac and virtual-box/ubuntu) within this doc — make sure you understand which window your in.

Final note: The solution shown below is based on establishing a common group id between the OSX and Ubuntu environments, so that the file permissions work. There may be other, more modern solutions. This one is really simple and understandable, and runs on bare bones basic unadorned installations.

**OSX: —————**

Note that is was done on a fresh out of the box 10.9.5 Mac, with nothing on it, not connected to a corporate network, nothing fancy running on it other than stock software. This is as simple as it gets.

When I did the default install on the Mac, **joe_public** is the admin user, and his uid was set to **501**.

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:/ joe_public$ id
uid=501(joe_public) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),999(vboxsf),401(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),501(access_bpf),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh)
```

Notice that the **uid** is **501** — this is the default first account id on OSX — nothing special

I created a few directories that I want to share on the Mac side — Note that I did not put them under my user directory for backup reasons.

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:/ joe_public$ mkdir /vdisk
Joes-MacBook-Pro:/ joe_public$ mkdir /vdisk/shared
Joes-MacBook-Pro:/ joe_public$ mkdir /vdisk/public 
Joes-MacBook-Pro:/ joe_public$ mkdir /vdisk/images

Joes-MacBook-Pro:vdisk joe_public$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   5 joe_public  admin   170 Oct  8 01:08 .
drwxrwxr-t  36 root        admin  1292 Oct  6 02:26 ..
drwxrwxrwx   2 joe_public  admin    68 Oct  6 01:08 images
drwxr-xr-x   3 joe_public  admin   102 Oct  8 01:07 public
drwxrwxrwx   4 joe_public  admin   136 Oct  8 00:45 shared
```

**VBOX: ——————**

Simple default virtual box and ubuntu installation - again, **joe_public** is the default admin created when I installed ubuntu.

Please note once again, that the name space between the OSX and Ubuntu is completely different. There is absolutely no relationship between the two names here.

```
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/media/sf_shared$ id
uid=1000(joe_public) gid=1000(joe_public)   groups=1000(joe_public),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
```

Created three mount points, using **Virtual Box's** Setting -> Shared Folders gui.

```
Name      Path              Auto-mount  Access
images    /vdisk/images     Yes         Full
public    /vdisk/pubic      Yes         Read-only
shared    /vdisk/shared     Yes         Full
```

NOTE:  I actually had to reboot my session for all these mount points to come up.

```
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$ mount | grep vboxsf
shared on /media/sf_shared type vboxsf (gid=999,rw)
public on /media/sf_public type vboxsf (gid=999,rw)
images on /media/sf_images type vboxsf (gid=999,rw)
```

Notice that the gid for these is 999 — this is the **vboxsf** group.

```
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$ grep 999 /etc/group
vboxsf:x:999
```

This was assigned automagicly by Virtual Box version 4.3.16 for us. The vbox documentation shows ways how to change this if you mount the path manually through the command line, but who’s going to remember that — Simply take the defaults that the GUI forces on us..

But it doesn't work (expected at this point -- that's what we are trying to solve)

```
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/$ ls /media/sf_shared
ls: cannot open directory /media/sf_shared: Permission denied
```

Note that at this point **joe_public** is not a member of that **vboxsf** group — and that’s going to be a problem until we fix it. FYI: These are the default groups assigned to the account when it is created.

```
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/media$ grep joe_public /etc/group
adm:x:4:syslog,joe_public
cdrom:x:24:joe_public
sudo:x:27:joe_public
dip:x:30:joe_public
plugdev:x:46:joe_public
lpadmin:x:108:joe_public
joe_public:x:1000:
sambashare:x:124:joe_public
```

So what we have at this point (we haven’t done anything yet to fix it)

```
•   On mac,   joe_public gid is 501
•   On linux, joe_public gid is 1000
•   On linux, vboxfs gid is 999
•   On mac,   vboxsf does not exist
```

We don’t want to change the gid of the user **joe_public** on either side, as that’s a pain in the ass on already installed systems, and doesn’t solve this for other users. The simplest solution is to make a matching group id — **vboxsf** — on the mac side, and make sure that **joe_public** is a member of it on both sides.

So, still on  vbox/ubuntu, make **joe_public** a member of the 999 **vboxsf** group

```
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/$ sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf joe_public
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/$ grep 999 /etc/group
vboxsf:x:999:joe_public
```

I think I logged out of my account and back in again here after I did this.

**OSX: —————**

Now we need to create a **vboxsf** group on the mac. I doubt that the name actually makes a difference here — it’s the **999** group id that’s important. Please remember that the directory system name spaces (as well as user names) are different between the host and the VM operating systems. But just to make life sane, we all call it **vboxsf** on the mac. Same reasoning why **joe_public** is used a user name on both sides.

OSX doesn’t have a simple add group command like linux does — so use the dscl command to do this in multiple steps. Please see the mac os documentation for more details on this.  Notice that we create the vboxsf group, and add joe_public to that group here.

```
sudo dscl . -create /Groups/vboxsf
sudo dscl . -create /Groups/vboxsf name vboxsf
sudo dscl . -create /Groups/vboxsf passwd "*”
sudo dscl . -create /Groups/vboxsf gid 999
sudo dscl . -create /Groups/vboxsf GroupMembership joe_public
```

So, at this point, we should have

```
•   On mac, joe_public gid is 501
•   On linux, joe_public gid is 1000
•   On linux, vboxfs gid is 999
•   On mac, vboxsf gid is 999
•   On linux, joe_public is member of vboxsf 
•   On mac, joe_public is member of vboxsf
```

The proof here is if it works — so that’s the next step

**VBOX: ——————**

cd into our directory and touch a file

```
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/$ cd /media/sf_shared
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/media/sf_shared$ touch foo
```

Check that we created a file successfully.

```
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/media/sf_shared$ ls -al
total 4
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  102 Oct  8 00:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   4096 Oct  8 00:30 ..
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 Oct  8 00:44 foo
```

**OSX: —————**

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:shared joe_public$ cd /vdisk/shared
Joes-MacBook-Pro:shared joe_public$ ls -al
total 0
drwxrwxrwx  3 joe_public  vboxsf  102 Oct  8 00:44 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 joe_public  admin   204 Oct  8 00:17 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 joe_public  vboxsf    0 Oct  8 00:44 foo

Joes-MacBook-Pro:shared joe_public$ touch bar
Joes-MacBook-Pro:shared joe_public$ ls -al
total 0
drwxrwxrwx  4 joe_public  vboxsf  136 Oct  8 00:45 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 joe_public  admin   204 Oct  8 00:17 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 joe_public  vboxsf    0 Oct  8 00:45 bar
```

**VBOX: ——————**

```
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/media/sf_shared$ ls -al
total 4
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  136 Oct  8 00:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   4096 Oct  8 00:30 ..
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 Oct  8 00:45 bar
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 Oct  8 00:44 foo
```

It all appears to be working..

**VBOX: —————— FINAL VERIFICATION**

What we are checking out here is that this whole thing depend upon the user **joe_public** being a member of the **vboxsf** group — and the simplest way is simply removing **joe_public** from the group

Removing user **joe_public** from group **vboxsf**

```
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$ sudo gpasswd -d joe_public vboxsf
log out/in ubuntu
```

Seeing if we can access it our directory -- and we can't, and this proves that is a group permission problem

```
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/$ ls /media/sf_shared
ls: cannot open directory /media/sf_shared: Permission denied
```

Add user back into **vboxsf**

```
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/$ sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf joe_public
log out/in ubuntu
```

It works again !

```
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$ ls -al /media/sf_shared
total 4
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  170 Oct  8 01:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root   4096 Oct  8 01:25 ..
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 Oct  8 00:45 bar
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 Oct  8 00:44 foo
```

**VBOX: -- ONE MORE PROBLEM -- symbolic links in vbox -------**

If you go into **/media/sf_shared**, you will find that symbolic links in shared directories simply don't work. This is a really big problem if you are trying to set up a full linux development environment on a shared drive.

```
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/media$ cd sf_images
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/media/sf_images$ ls
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/media/sf_images$ mkdir test
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/media/sf_images$ ln -s test test2
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘test2’: Read-only file system
```

By default, symbolic links aren't supported on virtual box shares. See below for explanations. Basically as I understand it, symbolic links are a security hole that were "fixed" in Virtual Box by disabling support for them in the 4.1.8 time frame (2011). I'm running 4.3.16 here...

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085

http://ahtik.com/blog/fixing-your-virtualbox-shared-folder-symlink-error/

Fortunately there is a back door to re-enable it, via the Host's **VBoxManage** command. Like always, please understand the security holes here that you may be opening. I'm on a stand-alone development machine, so this doesn't appear to be a problem.

**OSX: ------------**

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:shared pbradstr$ VBoxManage setextradata Ubuntu VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/shared 1
```

Note: **Ubuntu** is my vm's name, and **shared** is the shared directory name.

You can get the vm name like this:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:shared pbradstr$ VBoxManage list vms
"Ubuntu" {8461045a-1cee-4d44-8148-05920a47cee0}
Joes-MacBook-Pro:shared pbradstr$
```

And the shared folders name, either via the Virtual Box gui, or

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:shared pbradstr$ VBoxManage showvminfo Ubuntu | grep -A 5 "Shared folders"
Shared folders:  

Name: 'shared', Host path: '/vdisk/shared' (machine mapping), writable
Name: 'public', Host path: '/vdisk/public' (machine mapping), readonly
Name: 'images', Host path: '/vdisk/images' (machine mapping), writable
```

I rebooted the entire virtual box system here, I didn't figure out the minimum requirement for it to take.

Anyway, to test this, go back to you vbox window

**VBOX: ---------**

```
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/media/sf_images$ ln -s test test2
```

No error -- and to verify

```
joe_public@joe_public-ubuntu-VirtualBox:/media/sf_shared$ ls -ald test*
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 102 Oct  8 11:33 test
lrwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf   4 Oct  8 13:10 test2 -> test
```

**OSX: ----------**

And back on the mac side -- just to prove it all works

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:shared pbradstr$ ln -s test test3
Joes-MacBook-Pro:shared pbradstr$ ls -ald test*
drwxr-xr-x  4 joe_public  admin  136 Oct  8 13:20 test
lrwxr-xr-x  1 joe_public  admin    4 Oct  8 13:10 test2 -> test
lrwxr-xr-x  1 joe_public  admin    4 Oct  8 13:21 test3 -> test
```

Please note, I have only tested this on a OSX host, and Ubuntu virtual box client. The references that I listed above seemed to indicate that there might be an issue running a Windows based host.

**EXERCISE LEFT FOR THE STUDENT ———————**

The benefit of the method listed above is that it can run on a stand-along machine, with no network access. But if you think about this, this name-verses-id issue has got to be a common problem between any heterogeneous computing environments.

What other solutions are available where solutions to that problem are available? — Things like Active Directory (a Microsoft product) and the like might be able to solve this. It would be interesting to obtain a collection of those solutions and compare there various features and tradeoffs.

Answer (score 3):

Ever since VirtualBox v4.0, it's easy to solve these permissions issues! You don't need to worry about `mkdir`, `mount`, `chmod`, `umask`, etc. To access your auto-mounted shared folders (which appear in `/media` with `sf_` prefixes by default), there's only one thing you need to do: **Add your username to the `vboxsf` group via `sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf [username]`.**

For convenience, you may also want to create symbolic links to those shared folders within your `home` folder (e.g., `ln -s /media/sf_Stuff ~/Stuff`).

Source: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sf_mount_auto

Comment: Nice point about the symbolic link.

Answer (score 3):

After you create a shared folder in Virtualbox settings, Ubuntu will automatically mount it for you next time you boot up the system (you will see an icon on your desktop).

[image]

But if you are not using root account, you will not have permission to access it. What you need to do is to add your user account to a user group called 'vboxsf':

```
sudo usermod -G vboxsf -a $USER
```

Then logout and login again. You can access the shared folder now.

Answer (score 3):

For me all I needed to do was:

```
sudo adduser [username] vboxsf
```

That was enough for me to get access to the shared folders. The folder has a group of vboxsf, user only needs to be assigned to that group to get access.
If you need to set more strict access or more controllable access, you might need to go through the steps of mounting it manually with right userid-s.

For me the fstab solution didn't work and caused the machine not to boot correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found this, I tested and it worked in Ubuntu and Xubuntu, just the automount feature didn't worked for me

**I. Install Guest Additions**

Firstly, it is necessary to install the VirtualBox’s Guest Additions to the host system:

Choose in the VitualBox’s menu: Devices -> Install Guest Additions…

It mounts a new ISO for the host system.
    A new CD appears in Ubuntu (or mount it). Run as root the VBoxLinuxAdditions-x86.run installation script (because it is an Intel based Mac) in a Terminal window:

```
cd /media/cdrom
sudo VBoxLinuxAdditions-x86.run
```

Probably you will be asked to restart Ubuntu.

Installing the Guest Additions has many advantages such as adopting screen resolution (your window size is the system resolution, i.e. no scrollbars), easy mouse mode (no need to press the left command button to release the mouse cursor) and, what we are looking for, shared folders.

**II. Create Shared Folder**

The goal is to access a shared folder, what is an easier way than to use sshd or Samba.

Choose in the VitualBox’s menu: Devices -> Shared Folders...

- Click on the Add new shared folder button.
- Choose a Folder Path - a folder on your Mac harddrive, e.g. /Users/ondrej/Pictures.
- Choose a Folder Name - a name that identifies this shared folder in Ubuntu (as a host system), e.g. pictures.
- Select Make Permanent - if you would like to persist this shared folder definition.
- Click on OK.
- Click OK to close the list of shared folders.

**III. Mount Shared Folder**

Mount the created shared folder into a folder with permissions for your user. Let’s open a Terminal window on Ubuntu and:

Create a folder where will be the shared folder mounted. (Skip this step if have already a folder for this.)

```
mkdir DIR
```

e.g. (in /tmp)

```
mkdir share
```

Get your user uid:

```
id
```

The result will be something like:

```
uid=1000(ondrej)gid=1000(ondrej)groups=4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),
46(plugdev),112(lpadmin),119(admin),120(sambashare),1000(ondrej)
```

so uid of my user is 1000.
  Mount the shared folder SHARED_FOLDER_NAME into folder MOUNTED_FOLDER with ownership for user with uid USER_ID as root:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=USER_ID SHARED_FOLDER_NAME MOUNTED_FOLDER
```

e.g.

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000 pictures /tmp/share
```

Specifying the uid parameter enables writing to the shared folder for your user.
  The mounted folder MOUNTED_FOLDER (e.g. /tmp/share) contains files from the shared folder on your Mac harddrive. It is possible to write to the share folder as well.
  Optionally, a shared folder can be automatically mounted on the virtual machine start.
  Add the following line to the /etc/fstab file (as root, e.g. sudo vim /etc/fstab):

```
SHARED_FOLDER_NAME /PATH/TO/MOUNTED/FOLDER vboxsf uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

e.g.

```
pictures /tmp/share vboxsf uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

where the uid and gid values can be find in the output of the id command (see the step 2 for detailed example).
  The shared folder will be available also after a restart of the virtual machine.

Source: http://www.valibuk.net/2009/03/accessing-mac-os-x-harddrive-from-ubuntu-in-virtualbox-via-shared-folders/

Answer (score 0):

*Host OS*: *macOS* 
*VM (guest) OS*: *Ubuntu Server 16.04.5 LTS* 
*VirtualBox v5.2.18* 
Both host OS and guest OS must have same user (further in the text: **username**).

#### Stage 1: Install *VirtualBox Guest Additions*:

1.1. Locate the VirtualBox Guest Additions,

```
$ cd /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/
$ cp VBoxGuestAdditions.iso ~/Downloads/
```

1.2.  Start the VM

1.3.  Click the CD icon in the bottom right task bar

1.4. Select "Choose disk image..."" and search for the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso

1.5.  In the guest terminal type (you can also do this from the host terminal if you SSH into it):

```
$ sudo su
$ apt update
$ apt upgrade
$ apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic gcc make
$ mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
$ cd /mnt
$ sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
$ reboot
```

#### Stage 2: Shared Folders Setup:

2.1.  Create rules in VM:

- Stop the VM
- Go to `Settings > Shared Folders`
- Click in the `Add new port forwarding rule` green button in the top right of the window.
- Search and select the folder you would like to share (e.g.: **/path/to/shared/host_folder**)
- Select the `Auto-mount` and `Make Permanent` options
- Start the VM

2.2. To mount shared folder on `/opt` you must create `shared_folder_dir` subfolder and set appropriate permissions to it:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /opt/shared_folder_dir
$ sudo chmod ug+w -Rv /opt/shared_folder_dir
$ sudo chown username:username -Rv /opt/shared_folder_dir
```

2.3. Add ***username*** to the ***vboxsf*** group:

```
$ sudo adduser username vboxsf
$ sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf username
```

2.4. Reboot VM to apply changes:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

#### Stage 3: Auto mounting `host_folder` into `/opt/shared_folder_dir`:

3.1. Change VM's /etc/rc.local:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

and place following right above `exit 0`:

```
# 'folder_name' = given in the shared folders configuration
# 'path/to/shared/folders' = guest path to access the shared folders from
# 'id' = prints uid/gid
# sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid={uid},gid={gid} {shared_folder_name} {path/to/shared/folder}
sleep 5
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 host_folder /opt/shared_folder_dir
exit 0
<<< EOF >>>
```

> ***Note:***
>   I've added `sleep 5` to execute mount operation **after** VirtualBox Guest Additions has started. You can check that by `journalctl -b` command.

3.2. Reboot VM to apply changes:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

[See also](https://medium.com/@diegocasmo/virtualbox-shared-folders-ssh-from-osx-host-to-ubuntu-server-guest-tutorial-ef2db1722033)

Answer (score -1):

From https://askubuntu.com/a/171357/476506

```
# usermod -aG vboxsf user
```

Above command will give access to shared folder for "user".