# chmod: permissions of a directory don't change

Tags: chmod

I have some issue with `chmod`:

```
    mis@hell:/var/www/blah$ sudo chmod g+w .git -v
    mode of `.git' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0775 (rwxrwxr-x)
    mis@hell:/var/www/blah$ ls -la | grep git$
    drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   442 Mar  6 09:30 .git
```

It looks like `chmod` doesn't change permissions of a directory in fact (`rwx` vs `r-x` for group). Why?

Comment: Are you sure your filesystem is not mounted read only ?

Comment: Is the file on a regular, local filesystem? In particular, isn't it remote or NTFS?

Comment: Oh, yes, it's remote FS. But it isn't write only, `chmod` works with files. `$ grep www /etc/fstab
www /var/www/ vboxsf rw,uid=33,gid=33`

Comment: The fact that it is a remote share is a detail which I'd say deserves mention in the question. Also, the same question has been answered [before](http://askubuntu.com/q/171354/134479).