# USB ISO Lockout

Tags: boot, partitioning, intel, iso

Following a SSD malfunction, attempting to boot from an ISO (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS) on USB results in the boot agent (Intel GE v1.5.36) taking no action. It lists the USB as an option (as well as the new, blank SSD) and allows the user to toggle to and select it. But this results in a return to the same (device selection) prompt with no other action.

My first thought was that the USB media had been configured incorrectly, so I tried using two different USB drives (and ran through SE questions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171354/directory-permission-change-not-working),
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition), and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership)).

Can anyone think of what might be causing the hangup? ...or does the ISO have to be prepared in some way prior to boot? (It went from the mirror to the drives without modification.)

**Drive 1 (ext2 USB)**

Thinking it might be a permissions problem, the output of `ls -ld /media/user/name1` is

> drwxr-xr-x 3 user user 4096 Oct 22 12:32 /media/user/name1

Output of `df -hT`

> /dev/sdb1      ext2       15G  1.9G   12G  14% /media/user/name1

Output of `fdisk -l`

> Disk /dev/sdb: 15.4 GB, 15376318464 bytes
>
> 64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 14664 cylinders, total 30031872 sectors
>   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0xa399e795
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>
> /dev/sdb1   *        2048    30031871    15014912   83  Linux

**Drive 2 (FAT32 USB)**

Output of `ls -ld /media/user/name2`

> total 1916400
>
> 400 -rw-r--r-- 1 user user     403851 Jan 12  2017 Back Up Your Files to the Cloud.pdf
>
> 16 drwx------ 2 user user      16384 Apr  4  2017 SanDiskSecureAccess
>
> 8416 -rwxr-xr-x 1 user user    8603432 Sep 20  2016 SanDiskSecureAccessV3.1_win.exe
>
> 1907568 -rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1953349632 Oct 22 14:38 ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

Output of `df -hT`

> /dev/sdb1      vfat       15G  5.2G  9.2G  36% /media/user/name2

Output of `fdisk -l`

> Disk /dev/sdb: 15.4 GB, 15376318464 bytes
>
> 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1869 cylinders, total 30031872 sectors
>   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00000000
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>
> /dev/sdb1              32    30031871    15015920    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Comment: You cannot boot an ISO directly (normally). I do but have to use grub2 and its loopmount command. You use an installer that erases a flash drive, formats it to FAT32, adds boot flag, extracts ISO and adds a BIOS boot loader. The extracted ISO is already configured for UEFI boot. see this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb or if you only want UEFI: http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media

Comment: @oldfred Thanks; `mkusb` ended up working well.